# Access paginated properties?

Tags: laravel

If I `dd` my paginated model I get:

```
  #total: 500
  #lastPage: 100
  #items: Plank\Mediable\MediableCollection {#1309 ▶}
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://redpet.localhost/info"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
```

But if I return via an API route I get data such as:

```
"per_page":5,"prev_page_url":null,"to":5,"total":500
```

Is there a way, to get properties such as the `prev_page_url`, in my `dd` statement in my controller (via web routes)?

Comment: Check the API Reference for that class: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html (or https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html, not sure which one in Laravel 8)

Comment: @TimLewis thanks - you're a star

Comment: No problem! That API reference has been a lifesaver, but unless you know it exists, it's kinda hard to find. But yeah, all classes, methods, etc, and links to their code in the framework GitHub can be found in there :)